# How to filter object values?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

Let's say I have this javascript object

```
const recipe = {
  name: 'Negroni',
  ingredient1: 'Gin',
  ingredient2: 'Campari',
  ingredient3:'Vermouth',
  preparation: 'Stir gin, vermouth, and Campari in an ice-filled mixing glass until very cold, about 30 seconds.'
}
```

I need a loop which will return string with each ingredient value, hence 'Gin', 'Campari', 'Vermouth'.
How can I filter those values from this object?

I was trying to use for...in loop but I only accessed strings with propery names.

```js
const recipe = {
  name: 'Negroni',
  ingredient1: 'Gin',
  ingredient2: 'Campari',
  ingredient3:'Vermouth',
  preparation: 'Stir gin, vermouth, and Campari in an ice-filled mixing glass until very cold, about 30 seconds.'
}

for (const property in recipe) {
  console.log(property.includes('ingredient') ? property : null);
}
```

Comment: Instead of having ingredients listed like that why not have a property called `ingredients` and assign an array to it: `ingredients: ['Gin', 'Campari', 'Vermouth']`. Much easier to manage.

Comment: Just drink all the Gin and you will be loopy perhaps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the value of the key by using the property indexer:

`recipe[property]`

```js
const recipe = {
  name: 'Negroni',
  ingredient1: 'Gin',
  ingredient2: 'Campari',
  ingredient3:'Vermouth',
  preparation: 'Stir gin, vermouth, and Campari in an ice-filled mixing glass until very cold, about 30 seconds.'
}

for (const property in recipe) {
  console.log(property.includes('ingredient') ? recipe[property] : null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get values of keys that contain ingredient:

```
const recipe = {
  name: 'Negroni',
  ingredient1: 'Gin',
  ingredient2: 'Campari',
  ingredient3:'Vermouth',
  preparation: 'Stir gin, vermouth, and Campari in an ice-filled mixing glass until very cold, about 30 seconds.'
}

let arr =[]

for (const property in recipe) {
    property.includes('ingredient') && arr.push(recipe[property])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could conditionally add each value to an array.  For example:

```js
const recipe = {
  name: 'Negroni',
  ingredient1: 'Gin',
  ingredient2: 'Campari',
  ingredient3:'Vermouth',
  preparation: 'Stir gin, vermouth, and Campari in an ice-filled mixing glass until very cold, about 30 seconds.'
}

let ingredients = [];
for (const property in recipe) {
  if (property.includes('ingredient')) {
    ingredients.push(recipe[property]);
  }
}
console.log(ingredients);
```

Though, if possible, you're better off changing the data structure entirely.  Numbered properties like that are a dead giveaway that you need an array:

```js
const recipe = {
  name: 'Negroni',
  ingredients: ['Gin', 'Campari', 'Vermouth'],
  preparation: 'Stir gin, vermouth, and Campari in an ice-filled mixing glass until very cold, about 30 seconds.'
}

console.log(recipe.ingredients);
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides it would make more sense you already had your ingredients inside an array like `ingredients: ["Gin", "Campari", "Vermouth"],`

with the current data you have you could do it like:

```js
const recipe = {
  name: 'Negroni',
  ingredient1: 'Gin',
  ingredient2: 'Campari',
  ingredient3:'Vermouth',
  preparation: 'Stir gin, vermouth, and Campari in an ice-filled mixing glass until very cold, about 30 seconds.'
}

const ingredients = Object.entries(recipe)
  .reduce((a, [k,v]) => (/^ingredient\d+$/.test(k) && a.push(v), a), []);

console.log(ingredients)
```

where `/^ingredient\d+/` is a small regex that matches exactly:

```
^            Start of string
ingredients  Specific word
\d+          One or more digits
$            End of string
```